# Laravel - Orderby created_at date in posts table from threads table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a posts and threads table. My relation is: `posts.thread_id = threads.id`.

I am trying to create a forum with threads with many posts. I want to order the list by the `created_at` date from the post.

So: I create a new post and it's now linked to a thread. When I go to the homepage for the forum, it should order the threads using the updated posts in each thread. In other words, it's similar to when someone replies to a thread in stack overflow, it gets to the top.

I hope that makes sense.

My relation in `Thread.php`

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forum\Post', 'thread_id', 'id');
}
```

Relation in `Post.php`

```
  public function thread()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum\Thread', 'thread_id', 'id');
}
```

My code to arrange the threads:

```
$threads = Thread::all();
```

It just displays the threads in order of it's ID. Please help. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forum\Post', 'thread_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

**Edit**

Actually, upon further reading of your question, what I think you're after is this:

```
 protected $touches = array('threads');
```

Include this line in your Post model. This will update the timestamps on related models. Then you can sort your threads by the updated_at column.

Comment: Instead of `protected $touches` in the modal, I went with `$thread->touch()` in my controller when a new post was created. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$threads = Thread::latest('updated_at')->take(5)->get()
```

Replace the 'updated_at' field by whatever field you want to use to check for the newest threads. Change "5" to however many you want to grab. or use paginate().

Comment: But the thread's `updated_at` column is not being updated when the post is created.

Comment: Hey, sorry. I signed off after my last comment last night. Since you already have the posts model, just try this. `$threads = Post::thread()->latest('updated_at')->take(5)->get()`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for one-to-many relation:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

In a view:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->thread->title }}
@endforeach
```